# Inheriting and overriding synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, collections, thread-safety

If a class has synchronized methods, does its subclass also have the same synchronized methods, whether simply inherited or  overriden by the subclass?

Specifically,

- the legacy `Vector` has synchronized methods, and `Stack` is a subclass of `Vector`. Does `Stack`  also have synchronized methods?
- the legacy   `Hashtable` have synchronized methods, and  `Properties` is a subclass of `Hashtable`. Does  `Properties` also have synchronized methods?

Motivations of my questions are from [What are the replacements for legacy collections `Stack` and `Properties`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421899/what-are-the-replacements-for-legacy-collections-stack-and-properties)

Thanks.

Comment: Why would the `synchronized` property of a method disappear just because it's inherited?

Comment: Anyone wants to answer my questions on the specific collections `Stack` and `Properties`?

Comment: @Ben there's no point in answering the question for specific collection classes. It's the same answer for all classes.

Comment: @Andy My point is whether we need to find synchronized replacements for `Stack` and `Properties`. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated/1386288#comment81795220_1386288

Comment: @Ben How is your first and second question related? If you meant to ask whether `Stack` and `Properties` inherits `synchronized` methods, the answer is yes. If you meant to ask should Java have an alternate thread safe class like `Stack`, then that seems to be an unrelated question in comparison to your first question..

Comment: @CKing that unrelated question is my motivation. I have updated my post with it.

Comment: @Ben The first two questions *"the legacy Vector has synchronized methods, and Stack is a subclass of Vector. Does Stack also have synchronized methods?"* and *"the legacy  Hashtable have synchronized methods, and  Properties is a subclass of Hashtable. Does  Properties also have synchronized methods?*" have been answered in my post. The third question *"Motivations of my questions are from What are the replacements for legacy collections `Stack` and `Properties`?"* is answered in the question you linked to. What part of your question is not answered yet? Please explain clearly!

Answer (score 4):

> If a class has synchronized methods, does its subclass also have the same synchronized methods, whether simply inherited or overridden by the subclass?

A `synchronized` method from a super class can be overriden in a subclass as a non `synchronized` method and vice-versa.

If the subclass does not override a `synchronized` method but simply inherits it, the method will be inherited as-is as a `synchronized` method.

> I was wondering whether we need to find synchronized replacements
>   for Stack and Properties

`Stack` and `Properties` are thread-safe classes in the sense that most of their methods are `synchronized` (including the inherited methods from `Vector`/`Hashtable`). Although, that still doesn't safeguard them from being incorrectly used in a multithreaded context.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass inherits all the members (fields, methods, and nested classes) from its superclass. Constructors are not members, so they are not inherited by subclasses, but the constructor of the superclass can be invoked from the subclass.

However, a subclass does not inherit the private members of its parent class. However, if the superclass has public or protected methods for accessing its private fields, these can also be used by the subclass

So yes, synchronized methods are inherited by subclass. You can go through [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more details.

Comment: I have no idea what the first 3/4 of this answer has to do with answering the question.

Comment: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/mechanics.html says synchronised is not inherited.

Comment: Trying to explain inheritance in all.

Comment: @VeneetReddy it says "So the synchronized modifier is not automatically inherited when subclasses override superclass methods", as in if you override the method but omit the `synchronized`, the overridden method isn't synchronized.